# How to put a segmented control under the title in the navigation bar (Like Telegram App)

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar

I'm wondering how to put a segmented control under the title in the navigation bar ? Like that

[image]

I know how to put it at the place of the title: (Like that):

`navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControlView`

But I want to under the titleView and not a the place of the titleView, I find any elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Create a a UIView and two sub views to hold the text and the segment controller

```
let mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x,y,width,height)
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "bla bla" 
mainView.addSubView(label)
mainView.addSubView(segmentContoller)
```

Now add everything to NavBar:

```
navigationItem.titleView = mainView
```

And from now on play with the frames of each element for positioning

Comment: Thanks I'll try, how I can set properly the frame ? for all devices or may be with with constraint

Comment: that you'll have to experiment. I am not quite sure about it and I don't have enough free time to experiment myself. Hope you'll figure out by yourself. All I can do for now, is help you get your segment controller inside the Navbar. Did my code do its job?